# Send xml data to Server, Receive it and save into variables in php

Tags: php, xml, parsing, xml-parsing, client-server

I send xml data to a remote server(website). Getting response of it. 
Now I want to save that received values in variables for further use. But I am not able to do so.

**Here is the complete code:**

```
<?php
$xml = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?> <Request> <Source> <RequestorID Client="1921" EMailAddress="XML.ALTECH@TRAVELDEN.COM" Password="PASS" /> 
<RequestorPreferences Language="en" Currency="GBP" Country="GB"> 
<RequestMode>SYNCHRONOUS</RequestMode> </RequestorPreferences> </Source> 
<RequestDetails> <SearchHotelPriceRequest> <ItemDestination DestinationType="city" DestinationCode="LON" /> 
<ImmediateConfirmationOnly /> <PeriodOfStay> <CheckInDate>2015-12-08</CheckInDate> <Duration>2</Duration> 
</PeriodOfStay> 
<IncludeRecommended/> <Rooms> 

<Room Code="DB" NumberOfRooms="1"> <ExtraBeds> <Age>5</Age> </ExtraBeds> </Room> 
<Room Code="TB" NumberOfCots="2"> <ExtraBeds> <Age>10</Age> </ExtraBeds> </Room> 
<Room Code="SB" /> </Rooms> <StarRating MinimumRating="true">3</StarRating> 

<OrderBy>pricelowtohigh</OrderBy> <NumberOfReturnedItems>10</NumberOfReturnedItems> </SearchHotelPriceRequest> </RequestDetails> </Request>
' ;
$url = 'https://interface.demo.gta-travel.com/wbsapi/RequestListenerServlet';
   //setting the curl parameters.
 $headers = array(
    "Content-type: text/xml;charset=\"utf-8\"",
    "Accept: text/xml",
    "Cache-Control: no-cache",
    "Pragma: no-cache",
    "SOAPAction: \"run\""
 );
        try{

            $ch = curl_init();
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
            // send xml request to a server
            curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
            curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,  $xml);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 0);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
            echo $ch;
            $data = curl_exec($ch);

            echo $data;


            if($data === false){
                $error = curl_error($ch);
                echo $error; 
                die('error occured');
            }else{
                $newxml=$data;
                echo $data;
                echo '<pre>';
                echo htmlspecialchars(print_r($newxml, true));
                echo '<pre>';   
            $dataPOST = trim(file_get_contents($data));
            $xmlData = simplexml_load_string($dataPOST);                
            echo $xmlData->Response->ResponseDetails->SearchHotelPriceResponse->HotelDetails->Hotel['HasMap'];
            }
            curl_close($ch);
        }catch(Exception  $e){
            echo 'Message: ' .$e->getMessage();die("Error");
    }
?>
```

Error I am recieveing is "**Trying to get property of non-object**" at line and also warning like **Warning:  file_get_contents(**

```
$dataPOST = trim(file_get_contents($data));
            $xmlData = simplexml_load_string($dataPOST);                
            echo $xmlData->Response->ResponseDetails->SearchHotelPriceResponse->HotelDetails->Hotel['HasMap'];
```

Here is output code that i am reciveing from server in xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Response ResponseReference="REF_D_010_1921-1001448826920884">
    <ResponseDetails Language="en">
        <SearchHotelPriceResponse>
            <HotelDetails>
                    <Hotel HasExtraInfo="true" HasMap="true" HasPictures="true">
                        <City Code="LON"><![CDATA[London]]></City>
                            <Item Code="KEN8"><![CDATA[Grosvenor Kensington]]></Item>
                                <LocationDetails><Location Code="G1"><![CDATA[Central]]></Location>


                                    <Location Code="10"><![CDATA[Kensington]]></Location></LocationDetails>
                                    <StarRating>4</StarRating>
                                    <HotelRooms>
                                        <HotelRoom Code="DB" ExtraBed="true" NumberOfExtraBeds="1" NumberOfRooms="1"/>
                                        <HotelRoom Code="TB" ExtraBed="true" NumberOfCots="2" NumberOfExtraBeds="1" NumberOfRooms="1"/>
                                        <HotelRoom Code="SB" NumberOfRooms="1"/>
                                    </HotelRooms>
                    <RoomCategories>
                        <RoomCategory Id="001:GRO9:5144:S5063:5758:22498">
                            <Description><![CDATA[Standard Triple]]></Description>
                            <ItemPrice CommissionPercentage="0.00" Currency="GBP">1272.00</ItemPrice>
                            <Confirmation Code="IM">
                            <![CDATA[AVAILABLE]]>
                            </Confirmation>

                            <SharingBedding>false</SharingBedding>
                            <Meals>
                            <Basis Code="N"><![CDATA[None]]></Basis></Meals>
                        </RoomCategory>

                    <RoomCategory Id="001:KEN8:5144:S5063:5705:22498">
                        <Description><![CDATA[Standard Triple]]></Description>
                        <ItemPrice CommissionPercentage="0.00" Currency="GBP">1413.00</ItemPrice>
                        <Confirmation Code="IM"><![CDATA[AVAILABLE]]></Confirmation>
                        <SharingBedding>false</SharingBedding>
                        <Meals><Basis Code="B"><![CDATA[Breakfast]]></Basis>
                        <Breakfast Code="F"><![CDATA[Full]]>
                        </Breakfast></Meals>
                    </RoomCategory>
                </RoomCategories></Hotel>
            </HotelDetails>
        </SearchHotelPriceResponse>
    </ResponseDetails>
</Response>
```

Comment: `var_dump($xmlData)` is it a simplexml object? also HasMap is an attribute, you will need to use `->attributes()->HasMap`

Comment: var_dump dont work i have tried it.

Comment: It's impossible for var_dump to break.

Comment: any other solution then ? All i need to save retrieved xml values in variables

Comment: can you try it without the root XML element in your object path? `$xmlData->Response->ResponseDetails->` becomes `$xmlData->ResponseDetails->`. Also what does `var_dump($xmlData->asXML())` do? Do you see the same XML document you're expecting?

Comment: Did like this... and Error is in four lines. same error again n again. 
echo $xmlData->ResponseDetails->SearchHotelPriceResponse->HotelDetails->Hotel['HasMap'];

Answer (score 0):

`var_dump($xmlData)` is going to be "false" with your code...

Using `file_get_contents()` in invalid, you are trying to "load from disk" when `$data` is a string.

You are also trying to fetch an attribute incorrectly.

Locate this code:

```
$dataPOST = trim(file_get_contents($data));
$xmlData = simplexml_load_string($dataPOST);                
echo $xmlData->Response->ResponseDetails->SearchHotelPriceResponse->HotelDetails->Hotel['HasMap'];
```

Change it to this code:

```
$xmlData = simplexml_load_string($data);                
echo $xmlData->ResponseDetails->SearchHotelPriceResponse->HotelDetails->Hotel->attributes()->HasMap;
```

Comment: it seems like I have tried with this one. Still let me give a hit to it.